# Sort column of booleans in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am attempting to learn time series. I want to find the dates that are linked with a boolean value that is `True`. I then assigned the boolean to the `pd.DataFrame`.

I assigned the boolean statements to the column named `50+`, like this:

[image: I assigned the boolean statements to the list 50+]

How do I sort the `True` rows from the column `50+`?

I have searched the internet and have not found a solution. Since I passed the `50+` from a boolean to the dateframe, doesn't this make it a normal string that can be sorted by the sort value function?

Comment: Have you tried using the `.sort_values()` method of the dataframe, like you suggested? Did it work?

Comment: No, I cannot get it to work. I have tried .sort_values('True"), sort_index('True) etc. I am a complete loss. Do I have the syntax wrong for sort_values because i said x = df['50+'] 
x.sort_values('True')

Comment: Have you tried `df.sort_values(['50+', ])` ? The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) say to use the column name.

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify the column name:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(123)

>>> idx = pd.date_range('2018-10-05', periods=7, freq='D')

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'data': np.random.randn(idx.size),
...                    '50+': np.random.choice([0, 1], size=idx.size).astype(bool)},
...                   index=idx)

>>> df
                data    50+
2018-10-05 -1.085631   True
2018-10-06  0.997345   True
2018-10-07  0.282978  False
2018-10-08 -1.506295  False
2018-10-09 -0.578600  False
2018-10-10  1.651437   True
2018-10-11 -2.426679  False

>>> df.sort_values('50+')
                data    50+
2018-10-07  0.282978  False
2018-10-08 -1.506295  False
2018-10-09 -0.578600  False
2018-10-11 -2.426679  False
2018-10-05 -1.085631   True
2018-10-06  0.997345   True
2018-10-10  1.651437   True

>>> df.sort_values('50+', ascending=False)
                data    50+
2018-10-05 -1.085631   True
2018-10-06  0.997345   True
2018-10-10  1.651437   True
2018-10-07  0.282978  False
2018-10-08 -1.506295  False
2018-10-09 -0.578600  False
2018-10-11 -2.426679  False
```

If you're uncertain, you can always check the [docstring](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

The default is `ascending=True`, which will put `False`s first, because they are just 0s under the hood.  (While `True` is 1.)

If you'd like to filter to rows where this column is True, you can use:

```
>>> df[df['50+']]
                data   50+
2018-10-05 -1.085631  True
2018-10-06  0.997345  True
2018-10-10  1.651437  True
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find the dates that are linked with a boolean value that is
>   True.

You don't need to sort anything for this. You need only use Boolean indexing; in other words, construct a Boolean series or array with the same length as your dataframe index and apply it via `__getitem__`, called by the syntax `[]`.

So, instead of "assigning the Boolean to `pd.DataFrame`", just *index the index*!

```
index_filtered = df.index[df['50+']]
```

Comment: That is really clever man. Thank you for taking the time to respond! That will be a game changer for me.

Comment: @user10193731, No problem, don't forget to [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that helped by clicking the tick to the left of an answer.